# Database Link to access Columns in Table SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table in my SQL database using a datalink to another DB. 
I am using:

```
update TestTable
 SET some_column1=table.ColumnName1@dataBaseLink,
   some_column2=table.ColumnName2@dataBaseLink,
   some_column3=table.ColumnName3@dataBaseLink,
   some_column4=table.ColumnName4@dataBaseLink,
   some_column5=table.ColumnName5@dataBaseLink        
  where some_column=database.SomeColumn@dataBaseLink;
```

I am getting the error

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "database"."Variable1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

I know I am obviously trying to access the columns in my database link wrong... but I am not sure how to fix and/or access it.

I am using SQL delveloper.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of object is `database.Variable1` supposed to be?

Comment: they are car varchar of different lengths

Comment: I wasn't asking the data type. I was asking about the object type. For example is `Variable1` supposed to be a column on a table named `database`?

Comment: oh I'm sorry... that was a stupid answer. They are columns in database yes. I will change my naming scheme...

Comment: you cannot read column from remote table without joining that table in sql. remote links work on tables not column names

Comment: @rs. that's what I was afraid of... so I have to make a temp table in my db so and update from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using merge

```
MERGE INTO TestTable TGT
  USING (
         SELECT t.key, t.ColumnName1, t.ColumnName2, 
         t.ColumnName3, t.ColumnName4, t.ColumnName5
         from remotetable@dataBaseLink t
  ) SRC
  ON (TGT.KEY = SRC.KEY)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET some_column1=src.ColumnName1,
   some_column2=src.ColumnName2,
   some_column3=src.ColumnName3,
   some_column4=src.ColumnName4,
   some_column5=src.ColumnName5
```